# A string written twice on real iOS device, but correct on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, localization

The string is 'Match Points:'

on any real iOS device:

[image]

on simulator iPhone 14 Pro:

[image]

The chip is appeared when user selected and enabled search filter. There is the code on didSelectItemAt

**SeleectFilterTableViewCell.swift**

"filter_poin_balance" = "Match Points: %points%"

```
let dataFilter = selectedChips.filter { $0.code == userPoint }
if !dataFilter.isEmpty {
    selectedChips = selectedChips.filter() { $0.code != userPoint }
} else {
    let title = wcmsLocalized("filter_poin_balance")?.replacingOccurrences(of: "%points%", with: userPoint) ?? ""
    let selectedData = AmountPointSelected(isPoin: false, title: title, code: userPoint)
    selectedChips.append(selectedData)
}
```

This is the code where i summoned the chip on cellForItemAt

**SearchTableViewCell.swift**

pointChips = [AmountPointSelected]

```
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SearchItemCell.identifier(), for: indexPath) as? SearchItemCell {
    if indexPath.row == pointChips.count {
       cell.itemLabel.text = merchantTitle
    } else {
       cell.itemLabel.text = pointChips[indexPath.row].title
    }
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
                
}
return UICollectionViewCell()
```

How can the result is different between real device and simulator? How to fix on real device so that the "Match points:" not written twice?